# ruby script reading file line by line and add line

Tags: ruby

I am reading a file in ruby by below code

```
completeLine = ""
file.each_line do |line|
  completeLine = completeLine + line
end
```

now when i print completeLine  variable its show its content in multipal line like

```
<obj  id=\"pluvi\" border=\"0\"
clsid=\"clsid:VI\"
style=\"opacity: 0.0; background-color: #000000; width: 0px; height: 0px;\"></obj>"
```

i want it in 1 line only like

```
<obj  id=\"pluvi\" border=\"0\" clsid=\"clsid:VI\" style=\"opacity: 0.0; background-color: #000000; width: 0px; height: 0px;\"></obj>"
```

so i use **gsub** method to remove new line character like

```
line = line.gsub(" *\n+", ' ')
line = line.gsub(" *\t+", ' ')
```

but again after this i am not able to get content in 1 line.

to see the content present in file i used below method and got ouptput like this in **irb**

```
 text = File.open('G:/index.html').read

=> "<obj  id=\"pluvi\" border=\"0\"\n\tclsid=\"clsid:VI\"\n\tstyle=\"opacity: 0.0; background-color: #000000; width: 0px; height: 0px;\"></obj>"
```

So how can i solve above problem?

Comment: Please explain reason for down vote so i can improve my question from next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all the empty/white space in the line using [strip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-strip)

```
completeLine = ""
file.each_line do |line|
  completeLine = completeLine + line.strip
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[chomp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-chomp) will remove \n, \r, and \r\n, if $/ has not been changed from the default Ruby record separator:)

```
completeLine = ""
file.each_line do |line|
  completeLine = completeLine + line.chomp
end
```